# Inject controller in actor

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

Is it possible to inject an controller class in an UntypedActor?
What is the best way to get connection to an controller class?

```
package actors;

import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import dispatchers.PushNotificationDispatcher;
import play.Logger;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;

public class PushNotificationActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Inject
    PushNotificationDispatcher dispatcher;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        Logger.debug("PushNotificationActor started");
        dispatcher.createAndSendReminderPushNotification();
        Logger.debug("PushNotificationActor finished");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to do this like you wrote...Actors are encapsulated classes. The best option is to check if this code will work but IMO it won't...

You can try pass this injection through parameters like below:

```
Props props2 = Props.create(MyActor.class, your params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to inject instances into your Actor.

With Play **2.4** it works [out of the box](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaAkka#Dependency-injecting-actors), just inject like you would in a normal class.

I always inject into the constructor, e.g. here JPAApi:

```
public class MyActor extends UntypedActor {

  private final JPAApi jpa;

  @Inject
  public MyActor(JPAApi jpa) {
    this.jpa = jpa;
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I tryed to implement the code, but in my case the injected controller is always null.
Do you have some sample code?

Comment: I added an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's tricky, I also tried your code, but I have an NullPointerException
I added my code on github
https://github.com/aBuder/play-actor-sample